# Spinner (Spin.js.org) in Meteor React

Tags: reactjs, meteor, spinner

I'm trying to add a loading spinner. Per the docs for [html](http://spin.js.org/) and [meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/sacha/spin), I installed the atmosphere package. Here is my attempt:

```js
renderSpinner() {
  Meteor.Spinner.options = {
      lines: 13,
      ...
      left: 'auto' 
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('spinner');
    var spinner = new Spinner(options).spin(target);
}
```

And:

```js
render() {
  <span id="spinner"></span>
  {this.renderSpinner()}
}
```

But that doesn't produce desired outcome. So I guess my questions are:

1. How do I import the package into one of my files? (Or I don't need to?)
2. What is the equivalent of {{> spinner}} in React?
3. How do I make it work?

Sorry if these questions are very basic, I'm starting out and I bet I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm retarded. The solution is to just have

> var options = { lines: 13, ... };

Easy peasy